# Where is CVS setting(config) located at in FreeBSD usually?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, cvs

Where would the CVS pserver setting(config) be located at in FreeBSD usually?

I am trying, trying to hunt for the location of the setting(config) file with no results...

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking about the server or the client?
Did you look at the manpage cvs(1)?

The manpage describes the .cvsrc file and the environment variables
Checkout specific configuration is usually saved in the CVS directory

The server is usually run from inetd.conf